# Ruby OCIError Invalid Character, no semi-colon

Tags: ruby, oracle, activerecord

My apologies, I inherited a Ruby application/site with little training. I have been able to resolves many things without an issue but run into something when I go to connect to an Oracle DB.

> Blockquote I, [2011-07-11T16:35:01.237004 #6456]  INFO -- : OCIError: ORA-00911: invalid character: SELECT tc_testcycl_id FROM `ONLINE_OLS3_DB`.`TESTCYCL`  WHERE `ONLINE_OLS3_DB`.`TESTCYCL`.`tc_cycle_id` = 463 GROUP BY tc_testcycl_id (ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid)

I do not see the semi-colon that many forums talk about and suspect that it might be the single quotes but am not sure. Here is a code snip:

```
  class QCTestCycle < ActiveRecord::Base
set_primary_key "TC_TESTCYCL_ID"
```

end

```
  QCTestCycle.establish_connection(@qc_db[@environment_name])
  QCTestCycle.set_table_name "#{@application.qc_table_name}.TESTCYCL"

unique_tests = QCTestCycle.select("tc_testcycl_id").where(:tc_cycle_id => @application.qc_cycle_id).group("tc_testcycl_id").all
```

Any other information that I can provide?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The back-ticks in your error message are going to cause Oracle problems. Don't know how they got there but they need to go.

Comment: Thank you. Sadly I do not know how they got their either but at least it gives me a route to investigate.